# How can I set turn (relay) server In Asterisk. (webrtc)

Tags: server, webrtc, turn

I'm developing Voice chat Web-site with WebRTC.
But, I have a problem with NAT...And LTE Cellphone.

I found I need TURN server.

So, I installed Asterisk in my server.

I saw docs in [asterisk-wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Interactive+Connectivity+Establishment+%28ICE%29+in+Asterisk).

and setting like this :
==== sip.conf ====

```
...
icesupport=yes
...
```

==================
===== rtp.conf =====

```
turnaddr=my_server_ip
turnusername=username
turnpassword=password
```

==================

And, I restart Asterisk.

And, My webrtc code here:

```
var configuration = {
   "iceServers" : [
   {
      url: 'turn:my_server_ip:3478?transport=udp',
      credential: 'username', // NOT Hash
      username: 'password'
   },
   {
      url: 'turn:my_server_ip:3478?transport=tcp',
      credential: 'leeyw', // NOT Hash
      username: 'leeyw'
   }]
};
```

But, As I see, this turn server didn't run.
When I execue 'SIP SET DEBUG ON' and 'RTP SET DEBUG ON', I can't see any logs.

How can I install turn server in Asterisk.
Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

TURN is needed for the WebRTC client and not for the Asterisk server. This means that you don't have to configure turn on your Asterisk.

Just setup a [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) server and configure your WebRTC client accordingly.